# Rails - Making a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've made a comment system for my blog, and now I want to share with some friends. What do I have to do? I'm not familiar with plugins/engines/gems (in fact I don't even know the distinction between them).

My comment system has:

- Model (Comment.rb)
- Partial (_comment.erb.html)
- Some assets (comments.css, comments.js and 2 images)
- Some relationships (belongs to Post, has many Votes)

What I want is to offer some configurations, like using another model instead of Post.

You can see the comment system [here](http://jmorais.com/blog/hello-world). (Yes, it's totally inspired in Reddit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rails Plugins will be deprecated in Rails 4](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#plugins4_0), so the best option to go for you is to create a gem with dependency on the Rails gems you use for your gem (ActiveRecord, ActiveSupport and so on).

There are tons of tutorials how to build a gem out there, I personally like [Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler/) to build gems. If you want to know how to build a gem from scratch though, [look here](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#first-gem)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find Engines quite useful for such a use case.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html